# Why I cannot loading external data from D3js in React?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, fetch, external

I am trying to use D3 with react, but when I load external csv or json file from a folder, it won't work but instead return an array of the html file?

```
import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";

class D3 extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.startD3();
}

startD3 = () => {
    d3.csv("/data/Book1.csv").then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
    })
```

Comment: How are you serving `/data/Book1.csv` from your server?

Comment: the data folder is in the same folder with D3 folder that contains the D3 file. I tried different paths but none work.

Comment: Are you sure you are serving the file, and you are not trying to use a file system path? Are you using create react app?

Comment: yes I am using create react app

Comment: You could put the `Book1.csv` file in the `public` folder instead and write `d3.csv("/Book1.csv")`

Comment: thank you very much, you are superb , but can you please explain to me why it does not work if I put the file in a different folder?

Comment: You're welcome! `d3.csv` takes a route to send a request to, not a file system path. If you would have a server route called e.g. `/this/is/my/file.csv` you could use that, but not `/data/Book1.csv` in your regular file system. Everything in the `public` folder is served at the root `/` by create react app (webpack dev server under the hood).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d3.csv` will send a request to the path given to it, so you must make sure that the file is served by your server, and that it's just not a filesystem path.

You could put the file in the `public` folder and just use the `/Book1.csv` path instead.

```
d3.csv("/Book1.csv").then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
```